# why does any upgrade pause in chengelog0

Tags: upgrade, updates

Whenever I do an upgrade the system pauses and waits for me to press F2 before it continues, displaying often a changelog, is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

FOR EXAMPLE as shown below, the upgrade has paused:

```
Get:1 Changelog for libxslt1.1 (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/libx/libxslt/libxslt_1.1.26-14ubuntu0.1/changelog) [37.2 kB]
libxslt (1.1.26-14ubuntu0.1) quantal-security; urgency=low

  * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via malformed stylesheet
    - debian/patches/CVE-2012-6139.patch: check for empty values in
      libxslt/functions.c, libxslt/keys.c, add tests in tests/*.
    - CVE-2012-6139

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Thu, 28 Mar 2013 13:03:10 -0400

Get:1 Changelog for libpoppler28 (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/poppler/poppler_0.20.4-0ubuntu1.2/changelog) [42.7 kB]
poppler (0.20.4-0ubuntu1.2) quantal-security; urgency=low

  * SECURITY UPDATE: invalid memory access issues
    - debian/patches/CVE-2013-1788.patch: add checks in poppler/Function.cc,
      poppler/Stream.cc, splash/Splash.cc.
    - CVE-2013-1788
  * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via malformed documents
    - debian/patches/CVE-2013-1789.patch: validate data in splash/Splash.cc.
    - CVE-2013-1789
  * SECURITY UPDATE: uninitialized memory read
    - debian/patches/CVE-2013-1790.patch: properly handle refLine in
      poppler/Stream.cc.
    - CVE-2013-1790

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Fri, 08 Mar 2013 13:43:15 -0500

Get:1 Changelog for xdiagnose (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/x/xdiagnose/xdiagnose_3.2.3/changelog) [18.5 kB]
xdiagnose (3.2.3) quantal-proposed; urgency=low

  * xdiagnose.udev: Disable GPU apport hook from being triggered by udev.
    This should only be enabled during the development period.  Apport is
    disabled after release, but it appears the hook still gets triggered
    under certain circumstances.
    (LP: #1073626)

 -- Bryce Harrington <bryce@ubuntu.com>  Thu, 14 Feb 2013 12:38:26 -0800

~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
(END)
```

UPDATE: Actually it now pauses here and stops.. I cannot go any further. If I close terminal I get a message: There is still a process running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `less` pager program. Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to close these changelogs and continue the installation.

I have not seen this happening with most `apt-get upgrade`'s. I have only had a few times that such a changelog was shown to inform me about possible backwards incompatibilities (a security upgrade for MySQL on a Debian server).

Comment: Cool thanks... the strange thing it never used to stop. It'll stop whatever method I am using terminal/GUI, often pauses on displaying a /tmp/ I have to then press F2 to continue. Is there anyway to automate this?

Comment: @pst007x It looks like you have the `apt-listchanges` package installed. It is not installed by default and you can remove it which would effectively fix this annoyance for you.

Comment: @jokerdino Cool, removed it now... Nice one dude... appreciate the advice!